# Cannot assign string to null within a string array

Tags: java, arrays

Good day,

I have to create a dynamic array class which will represent a string array with dynamic size. I have created the add method and now I have some difficulties with the removeElement method.

Here is my code:

```
public class DynamicArray {

public String[] dynamicString = new String[0];

public void addElement(String input) {
    int loc = findFreeSpace();

    if (loc >= 0) {
        dynamicString[loc] = input;
    }
    else {
        dynamicString = Arrays.copyOf(dynamicString, dynamicString.length + 1);
        dynamicString[dynamicString.length - 1] = input;
    }

}

public void removeElement(String input){
    for(String eachElement : dynamicString){
        if(eachElement.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) ; eachElement = null;
    }
}

private int findFreeSpace() {
    for (int i = 0; i < dynamicString.length; i++) {
        if (dynamicString[i] == null) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    DynamicArray array = new DynamicArray();

    array.addElement("a");
    array.addElement("b");
    array.addElement("c");
    array.addElement("d");

    array.removeElement("a");
    System.out.println(array.dynamicString[0]);
}
```

In the main method 4 String elements are added to the array object. I am using the removeElement method afterwards to remove a particular string element from that object's dynamicString. However, this method fails to work and the system.out.println prints "a" (instead of null) in the console.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're doing this instead of using an ArrayList?

Comment: You made a typo. Remove the `;` before `eachElement = null;` in `if(eachElement.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) ; eachElement = null;` (note that this by itself doesn't solve your problem, look at @JBNizet's answer)

Comment: @Human I guess that the idea is to learn about arrays. I'm a bit partial against lessons that force the student to use a method that should never be used in real life though. You learn to use an array but now you have to unlearn that an array can be used as a list. Hopefully the next lesson...

Comment: thanks fellas, Nizet's answer has fixed my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eachElement` is a copy of the reference in the array, and you're assigning a new value (null) to this copy. So the original reference is left unmodified. You need a traditional loop, which modifies `dynamicString[i]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dynamicString.length; i++){
    if (dynamicString[i].equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
        dynamicString[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the ";" after the if.

Also, as said in the comments you are modifying only the local variable. Use a for loop instead of a foreach loop to iterate through the index of your array and then once you've got the index of the element you want to change you can update your array

Comment: That statement is correct but it doesn't solve the problem as he's still not modifying the array - he's only modifying a local variable `eachElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
for(Iterator<String> it = dynamicString.iterator; it.hasNext(); ){
    String eachElement = it.next();
    if(eachElement.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) ;
    eachElement = null;
}
```

Can you see why it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems

1.';' after if means eachElement = null gets executed for every iteration

2.eachElement = null will not have no affect on array it is a seperate reference, you should use old style for loop in this case and access array element using index.

```
public void removeElement(String input){
    for(String eachElement : dynamicString){
        if(eachElement.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) ; eachElement = null;
    }
}
```

Other best option is to use `ArrayList`.

Comment: thanks mate, I know ArrayList is better but this is a mini-assignment in which I have to create a dynamicArray